# noetherian quotients and a finitely generated ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian

Suppose $A$ is a ring and $a$ and $b$ are ideals such that one of them is finitely generated. Also suppose $A/a$ and $A/b$ are noetherian. Apparently this implies $A/ab$ is notherian.

I was wondering if someone could give me a hint or point me in the write direction because i am pretty stuck.

Comment: $A/ab$ is not a quotient of $A/a$.

Comment: @ darij grinberg is this directed towards me or zev chonoles? I noticed this also. It would be pretty cool if $A/ab$=$(A/a)/b$ but it doesnt.

Comment: @ZevChonoles its cool i forgive you.

Comment: a big part of my confusion with this problem is that i see no very simple connection between $A/a$ , $A/b$ and $A/ab$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $a$ is finitely generated. One has an exact sequence $0\to a/ab\to A/ab\to A/a\to 0$. $a/ab$ is a finitely generated module over $A/b$ and hence Noetherian. Since $A/a$ is Noetherian, we are done.

Comment: thanks for this answer, but it is not extremely obvious to me why $a/ab$ is finitely generated.

Comment: What? I thought your assumption is one of $a,b$ is finitely generated. If $a$ is finitely generated, surely so is $a/ab$, being a quotient.

Comment: my bad i wasn't thinking correctly

Comment: also can you please give me some of your intuition for making this exact sequence.

Comment: Well, I do not know about intuition, but somehow you have to relate $A/ab$ with $A/a,A/b$ as you yourself correctly observed and you try the few ways you can and hope for the best.